# Explanation of fundamental groups $\pi_1(X_0,x_0)\approx\pi_1(X,x_0)$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, group-isomorphism, fundamental-groups

**Theorem**. Let $x_0\in X,$ and let $X_0$ be the path component of $X$ containing  $x_0.$ Then $\pi_1(X_0,x_0)\approx\pi_1(X,x_0).$

What is this theorem telling?

Is it telling that the fundamental group of whole space $X$ based at $x_0$ is isomorphic to the fundamental group of $X_0$ based at $x_0$?

How is that it is true? If you take the $\pi_1(S^1,1)$ and $\pi_1(S^n,1)$ and use this theorem for each of them, would not be a contradiction?

Like this $π_1(S^1,1)≈π_1(X,1)$ and $π_1(S^n,1)≈π_1(X,1).$ Hence $π_1(S^1,1)≈π_1(S^n,1).$

(sorry for not to be clear)

If you could give me an intuitively explanation, that would be enough. Thank you.

Comment: Loops based at $x_0$ are paths. So they must live in the path component $X_0$, in particular.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "If you take the $\pi_1(S^1, 1)$ and $\pi_1(S^n, 1)$ and use this theorem for each of them (...)". $S^1$ is not a path component of $S^n$.

Comment: @AloizioMacedo I meant $\pi_1(S^1,1)\approx\pi_1(X,1)$ and $\pi_1(S^n,1)\approx\pi_1(X,1).$ Hence $\pi_1(S^1,1)\approx\pi_1(S^n,1).$

Comment: In order to get your contradiction, you have applied the theorem incorrectly. You cannot apply a theorem that has a given object $X$ without saying exactly what space the symbol $X$ represents. Did you have some particular space $X$ in mind?

Answer (score 1):

Let’s use your example of a point $p$ on the sphere $S^n$ and show why this isn’t a contradiction. Your theorem states

$$\pi_1(X_0, x_0) = \pi_1(X,x_0).$$

Here, we have $x_0 = p$ and $X = S^n$. By definition, the subspace $X_0$ is the path-connected component of $X$ containing $x_0$. We don’t get to pick what $X_0$ is — we only get to pick the base point $p$ *and then* $X_0$ is given to us. Since $S^n$ is a path-connected space, i.e. it has one path-connected component, this implies that $X_0 = S^n$. Thus, your theorem says in this case that

$$\pi_1(S^n, p) = \pi_1(S^n,p).$$

Hopefully this equality is believable!

Comment: My idea was not to consider $X=S_n$ but any other arbitrary $X$. I meant like this $\pi_1(S^1,1)\approx\pi_1(X,1)$ and $\pi_1(S^n,1)\approx\pi_1(X,1).$ Hence $\pi_1(S^1,1)\approx\pi_1(S^n,1).$

Comment: You cannot apply the theorem using "any other arbitrary $X$". You can only apply it to an $X$ and $X_0$ that satisfy the hypotheses of the theorem. Those hypotheses are: that $X$ is a topological space, $x_0$ is a point of $X$, and $X_0$ is the path component of $X$ that contains $x_0$. What space $X$ and point $x_0 \in X$ did you have in mind?

Comment: @LeeMosher I guess I got confused. I did not think in a particular space $X$